# How to valiadate the date against sql injection in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date

I've tried all approaches

with regex,

```
if @fromdate.to_s =~ /\A(?:0?[1-9]|1[0-2])\/(?:0?[1-9]|[1-2]\d|3[01])\/\d{4}\Z/
```

I just wanted to avoid the blind sql injection

So please comment your suggestions.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would you consider `"02/31/9999"` a valid date in your context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can parse the string using [`DateTime.parse`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-c-parse) Then pass the parsed date to SQL query. It's easier and more reliable than validation using regex.

Alternatively you can use [`DateTime.strptime`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-c-strptime) with the format you're expecting, as suggested @Cary Swovelad.

Comment: Regarding "...with the format you're expecting.", [DateTime::parse](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-c-parse) does not take a pattern as an argument. Moreover, `DateTime.parse "You may find that parse sometimes gives surprising results" #=>  #<DateTime: 2018-05-01T00:00:00+00:00 ((2458240j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>`. [DateTime::strptime](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-c-strptime) would be a better choice. With that an exception must be dealt with if the string doesn't match the format string.